# VB.NET: Playing song and adding to queue while iterating in main function

Tags: vb.net, audio

I'm trying to play a song or add the song to an audio queue while the main function executes in Visual Basic. Here's some pseudo code to illustrate my problem:

```
// do {
// some stuff
if(goalReached) { 
    if (songIsPlaying) playAgainAfter();
    else playSong();
}
// } while
// end
```

So while the main function is iterating, I need to the song to be playing, and if it's playing, I need to queue it.

I've been trying to use Audio.Play("song.wav", BackgroundLoop) and a timer to "pseudo-queue" the song by adding to the timer, but it seems like a really bad solution.  I've also thought about using a counter, but that wouldn't work because I need to be executing the main function concurrently.  Is there something I'm not thinking of?

Comment: If you are making a game for Windows, look at Wasapi or DirectSoundApi for better results. Audio.Play is not the best api to make a game.

Comment: Sounds like something from a .Net library, is this actually a VB6 question?

Comment: @Turrican, It's actually a stimuli experiment for a research lab, but essentially the same thing.  I'll definitely take a look at Wasapi and DirectSoundApi, thank you for that.

Comment: @Bob77 You're totally right, I meant to put VB.NET not VB6.  Thanks!

Comment: So fix it. Edit your question. You stole money off me by making me download a pointless page. And you've known for 41 minutes.